Can receive Bounce, Delivery notification but not Complaint notification with Amazon SES
I'm setting up an AWS SES to send and get the feedback back, then forward the message to SNS topic. The problem is I can receive Bounce and Delivery notification but not Complaint when I click Report as spam in receiver's mailbox.
I already configured to handle Complaint event type in SES Configuration Set as well as in SNS.
I'm appreciated if you guys can help me. Thank you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
